# What resolution should I use for the Android Maps API V2 marker

Tags: android, icons, google-maps-android-api-2

I am currently using Maps API V2 and a custom marker with a custom icon: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/android/marker#customize_the_marker_image

The problem is that the icon size is not described in the documentation.

I currently use a 48*48px picture resulting of some iterations and some tests but would like to provide  a pixel perfect icon.

Any idea?

Comment: Did you ever figure this out?

Comment: Still using 48*48 without any reason, except that looks correct.

Comment: Thanks.  FWIW, the android-maps-utils demo uses 150*150 in xhdpi folder, although that's in the context of custom markers created within that library - https://github.com/googlemaps/android-maps-utils/tree/master/demo/res/drawable-xhdpi.